# qsort of multidimensional array in c leading to segfault

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, qsort

I am trying to sort a 2D array of doubles using qsort() in C.  The arrays contain 3D point data, which is read in from a file using fscanf.  My programming skills are rather limited, but I have really large datasets that I need to deal with.  Sorry in advance if my code sucks.

23127.947, 23127.947, 23127.947
523127.790, 523127.790, 523127.790
523127.747, 523127.747, 523127.747
523127.761, 523127.761, 523127.761
523127.768, 523127.768, 523127.768
(...for 3,158,632 points)

I've used printf to isolate that the problem in my code seems to be the qsort() line, which causes a segmentation fault.  From other questions on Stack Overflow that I read, it could be a problem with my "compare" function.  Examples for doing a 1D array seemed easy, but the examples I saw for 2D arrays didn't go into comparing the other dimensions (first X, then if X1 = X2, compare Y, then if Y1 = Y2, compare Z).

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i,j,c;
    double x,y,z;
    int ROWS = 3158632;
    int COLS = 3;
    char buffer[100];

    double** data = Make2DDoubleArray(ROWS, COLS);

    //Open the plot file to read in, and have an output write file
    FILE *fp = fopen("Plot_1-2.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
        exit;
    }

    fgets(buffer, 100, fp); //Ignore header

    for(i=0; ; i++){
        if ((c = fgetc(fp)) == EOF){
            break;
        }
        fscanf(fp,"%lf, %lf, %lf",&x, &y, &z);
        data[i][0] = x;
        data[i][1] = y;
        data[i][2] = z;
    }

    printf("First 5 unsorted numbers:\n");
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
        printf("Line %d: %.3lf, %.3lf, %.3lf\n",j, data[j][0], data[j][0], data[j][0]);
    }
    printf("Last 5 unsorted numbers:\n");

    for(j=ROWS-5;j<ROWS;j++){
        printf("Line %d: %.3lf, %.3lf, %.3lf\n",j, data[j][0], data[j][0], data[j][0]);
    }

    /* Sort array using Quicksort algorithm: */
    printf("Sorting...\n");
    qsort(data, ROWS, COLS*sizeof(double), &compare);

    printf("First 10 sorted numbers:\n");
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        printf("Line %d: %.3lf, %.3lf, %.3lf\n",j, data[j][0], data[j][0], data[j][0]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
        free(data[i]);
    }
    free(data);

    return 0;
}

double** Make2DDoubleArray(int arraySizeX, int arraySizeY) {  
    double** theArray; 
    int i; 
    theArray = (double**) malloc(arraySizeX*sizeof(double*));  
    for (i = 0; i < arraySizeX; i++)  
        theArray[i] = (double*) malloc(arraySizeY*sizeof(double));  
    return theArray;  
}

int compare(const void *arg1, const void *arg2) {
    //double a, b, c, d, e, f;
    double *a = (double*)arg1;
    double *b = (double*)arg2;
    double *c = ((double*)arg1 + 1);
    double *d = ((double*)arg2 + 1);
    double *e = ((double*)arg1 + 2);
    double *f = ((double*)arg2 + 2);

    if(a > b)
        return 1;
    else if(a < b)
        return -1;
    else {
        if(c > d)
            return 1;
        else if(c < d)
            return -1;
        else {
            if(e > f)
                return 1;
            else if(e < f)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if telling qsort to go "COLS * sizeof(double)" is the wrong way to do it with how I allocated the memory for the 2D array?  Would treating this problem as a 1D array make the rest of it work?  I'd prefer to keep it as a 2D array, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this means anything without headers like `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, etc...

Please explain `exit;`. I think you mean `exit(0);`.

There are a few problems in your `main`. Because of that `fgetc`, your code potentially loses the most significant digit of your first value, which is a subtle bug. If you want to test for EOF, test the return value of `scanf` (*Jee! I didn't think of that! I wish they wrote these things in manuals!* Duh, they do...). The example at the end of the file is better than this, because that example ensures that three values are actually parsed by `fscanf`.

```
for(size_t i=0; fscanf(fp,"%lf, %lf, %lf",&x, &y, &z) != EOF; i++){
    data[i][0] = x;
    data[i][1] = y;
    data[i][2] = z;
}
```

There's a problem in your `Make2DDoubleArray` function. It allocates *many* disjoint arrays, which `qsort` can't handle. Isn't it much cleaner to allocate your array in one step?

```
void *Make2DDoubleArray(size_t x) {  
    double (*theArray)[3] = malloc(x * sizeof *theArray);
    return theArray;
}
```

`theArray` is declared as a pointer to an array of 3 doubles. You don't even need a `Make2DDoubleArray` for this.

There's a problem in the `compare` function.

```
double *a = (double*)arg1;
double *b = (double*)arg2;
```

`a` and `b` are pointers,

```
if(a > b)
    return 1;
else if(a < b)
    return -1;
```

... yet your code compares them as integers, rendering the sort malfunctional. The address of `array[0]` will always be less than the address of `array[1]`.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int j,c;
    double x,y,z;
    size_t ROWS = 3158632;
    size_t COLS = 3;
    char buffer[100];
    double (*theArray)[COLS] = malloc(ROWS * sizeof *theArray);

    //Open the plot file to read in, and have an output write file
    FILE *fp = fopen("Plot_1-2.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fgets(buffer, 100, fp); //Ignore header

    for(size_t i=0; fscanf(fp,"%lf, %lf, %lf", &x, &y, &z) == 3; i++){
        data[i][0] = x;
        data[i][1] = y;
        data[i][2] = z;
    }

    printf("First 5 unsorted numbers:\n");
    for(size_t j=0; j<5; j++){
        printf("Line %zu: %.3lf, %.3lf, %.3lf\n", j, data[j][0], data[j][0], data[j][0]);
    }
    puts("Last 5 unsorted numbers:");

    for(size_t j=ROWS-5; j<ROWS; j++){
        printf("Line %zu: %.3lf, %.3lf, %.3lf\n", j, data[j][0], data[j][0], data[j][0]);
    }

    /* Sort array using Quicksort algorithm: */
    puts("Sorting...");
    qsort(data, ROWS, sizeof *data, compare);

    puts("First 10 sorted numbers:");
    for(size_t j=0;j<10;j++){
        printf("Line %zu: %.3lf, %.3lf, %.3lf\n", j, data[j][0], data[j][0], data[j][0]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(data);

    return 0;
}

int compare(const void *arg1, const void *arg2) {
    double (*x)[3] = arg1;
    double (*y)[3] = arg2;

    if ((*x)[0] > (*y)[0])
        return 1;
    else if ((*x)[0] < (*y)[0])
        return -1;
    else if ((*x)[1] > (*y)[1])
        return 1;
    else if ((*x)[1] < (*y)[1])
        return -1;
    else if ((*x)[2] > (*y)[2])
        return 1;
    else if ((*x)[2] < (*y)[2])
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I didn't paste the headers in because I was trying to cut down a little on how much I put here.  In the future I'll include that.  Do you think staying with a 2D array is best, or should I create a point struct like SpacedMonkey mentioned?

Comment: @PeterOlsoy The types are all the same. An array would be more specific ("best") for internal documentation. To elaborate: It's easier to follow `double (*)[...]` than `struct ...`, because you have to go back and look up the struct before you know which types/members it stores. If one of the objects ever changes in type, then you'll probably want to use a `struct` and `union`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. It didn't like the change of j from int to size_t later on, so I just got rid of the reinitializations (kept it int). I have two final questions, (1) why did you change a bunch of the int's to size_t, is there a benefit or is it more of a style choice? (2) when I compile with gcc it gives me a warning "In function ‘compare’: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]", is that something I should fix? It seems to run fine.

Comment: @PeterOlsoy Please don't ask double barreled questions. Think about the information you want to gather, and ask a question that asks for that information. Make sure you `#include <stddef.h>` for `size_t`, otherwise it won't be defined. 1. `size_t` is guaranteed to be able to store the largest value that `sizeof` gives. `int` isn't. Consider what might happen if `int` can only store values between -32767 and 32767. 2. There's no harm done there, but warnings shouldn't be ignored. Change `double (*x)[3]` to `const double (*x)[3]`. Same for `y`. That should fix the warnings.

Comment: I had the include, the problem was that at the beginning of main j is initialized as "int j;" and then in the for loops it is reinitialized as "size_t j=0;" I believe the problem would be resolved by removing "int j;" at the beginning. Thanks for the explanation of int vs size_t.

Answer (score 2):

`qsort` expects the sorted elements to come in a contiguous block of memory. You can still keep your data in a 2D array, if all your cells constitute a contiguous block of memory that can be interpreted as an 1D array and used with `qsort`.

Instead of allocating memory separately for each row as you do in `Make2DDoubleArray`, allocate memory for all rows at once. Then, in addition to what you return now: an array of pointers to rows; you will also have to return (using argument-by-pointer) the memory block containing all of your rows.

You are allocating memory for each row

```
for (i = 0; i < arraySizeX; i++)  
    theArray[i] = (double*) malloc(arraySizeY*sizeof(double));
```

while you could allocate the memory in one step

```
 double *cells = malloc(sizeof(double) * arraySizeX * arraySizeY);
 if (cells == NULL) { ... }
 for (i = 0; i < arraySizeX; i++)
     theArray[i] = &cells[arraySizeY * i];
```

Then you will have two arrays: an array of pointers to rows which you have now (called `theArray` in your code); and a new 1D array that keeps all rows (not pointers to rows, but the arrays of cells) (<strike>and in effect, all cells</strike> where each row, a triplet, is one datapoint) and can be used for `qsort` (in my code called `cells`).

<strike>Then, pass the latter one - `cells` (and not `data`) to qsort</strike>

```
    qsort(cells, ROWS * COLS, sizeof(double), &compare);
```

Also note that the call in the code in the question

```
    qsort(data, ROWS, COLS*sizeof(double), &compare);
```

is wrong, because you are not sorting an amount of `ROWS` rows, each with a size of `COLS*sizeof(double)`.

EDIT: Uh, my apologies. I misunderstood that you have a 2D array of entries, but now I see that COLS represents fields of one cell. In which case you would be better of with @SpacedMonkey's solution.
Just for reference, my answer would also work, then you would call qsort like you did, but on cells

```
    qsort(cells, ROWS, COLS*sizeof(double), &compare);
```

Comment: I have struggled a bit dealing with allocating memory, but isn't that what "Make2DDoubleArray" does?  If not, could you explain a little bit more what I would need to add to it?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: In "Make2DDoubleArray", I return "TheArray"...would I now return "cells" instead?  From what I understand, I can only return one of the two and then the other will no longer be accessible in main?  I suppose I could move it to main since I only call the function once and don't really plan on calling it again.

Comment: @PeterOlsoy You should pass a third argument to the function, `double** cellsOut` and use it `*cellsOut = cells;` in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a struct for the data instead:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} point_data;
```

Then you only need a 1 dimensional array of this new type:

```
point_data *array = malloc(linesRead * sizeof *array);
```

And your comparison function remains fairly similar:

```
int compare(const void *arg1, const void *arg2) {
    point_data *point1 = arg1,
               *point2 = arg2;

    if ( point1->x > point2->x ) {
        return 1;
    else if ( point1->x < point2->x ) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        if ( point1->y > point2->y ) {
            return 1;
        else if ( point1->y < point2->y ) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            if ( point1->z > point2->z ) {
                return 1;
            else if ( point1->z < point2->z ) {
               return -1;
            } else {
               return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, please don't hardcode the number of points, instead count the number you read in.

Comment: I had originally planned on dynamically allocating my array and then using realloc()...but I figured I could do that later.  I suppose I could also loop through the file once to count the number of points and then allocate memory/create the array.

Comment: I'd probably use a vector similar to this implementation but with shrinking - https://github.com/nickjacob/C-Vector